# Add a column with values in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column with a list of words.

I filtered my twitter dataset by selecting the rows that include "RT @" in the text column. Now I have a list of user names (starting with "@"). I am trying to create a new column consisting of usernames (such as @MSNBC), next to my original dataset. If there's no RT @ in the text, it could be filled with NA. I need to fix my last line (code):

```
# filter retweet 
retweet <- data0 %>%
  filter(str_detect(text, "RT @")) #text row: filter rows which contain "RT" at the beginning
head(retweet$text)
nrow(retweet) #11,084 are retweets (total N: 15,377)

retweet[grep("@", retweet$text),]
a<- retweet %>% str_extract_all("RT @[^\\s]+")
head(a) #here, I got a list of account names (such as RT @MSNBC)

#create column RT
data0$RT <- (newColname = "RT") #how can I attach a list "a" here?
```

This is my reproducible sample: https://www.mediafire.com/file/mq483ch09ou5ias/data0.csv/file

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  I guess you don't need the `filter` step i.e. `data0 %>% mutate(RT = str_extract_all(text, "RT @[^\\s]+"))`. The `str_extract_all` returns a `list`

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I added my reproducible sample here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/mq483ch09ou5ias/data0.csv/file

Comment: Try the solution Iin the comments

Comment: Thanks! I tried mutate() that you suggested--it did create a new column, but the values for the RT column look like these: <chr [0]>, <chr [0]>, <chr [0]>, <chr [0]>, <chr [1]>...

Comment: It is a `list`column as I mentioned.  If you need to `paste` multiple elements, you can use `library(purrr); data0 %>% mutate(RT = map_chr(str_extract_all(text, "RT @[^\\s]+"), toString))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_extract` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data0 <- data0 %>% mutate(newColname = str_extract(text, "RT @[^\\s]+"))
data0
```